# What makes the THR input well defined in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

In the datasheet for the MIC1555 there is an example of an rising edge detector, see image.
I can't figure out why the THR pin is well defined in that circuit. If there was a resistor, 1M or so, between THR and ground it would make sense. But now it looks floating to me.

[image: rising edge detector]

[edit]
Would adding a resistor in the M-ohm range between THR and GND cause problems with this circuit? Given that the INPUT capacitor is matched so that a rising edge is actually detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works very nicely, the way it is. There's no trick in it. :)

[image: 555]

[image: 555-1]

> The  MIC1555  may  be  triggered  by  an  AC-coupled
> rising edge, as shown in Figure 5-6. The pulse begins
> when the AC-coupled input rises, and a diode from the
> output holds the THR input low until TRG discharges to
> 1/3VS. This circuit provides a low-going output pulse.

5.4 Rising-Edge Triggered Monostable Circuit ([PDF](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC1555-57-IttyBitty-RC-Timer-Oscillator-DS20005730B.pdf) page 12).

Comment: But that doesn't explain how the pin can, in effect, be left floating. What prevents it being triggered by stay pickup?

Comment: There is a **charged** capacitor (10nF) at the input and the CMOS input will not discharge this.

Comment: The 10nF capacitor [voltage](https://imgur.com/a/wmXnlcO) (lower diagram).

Comment: If that's the case then the 50 nA threshold current must be maintaining the charge on the input capacitor and not draining it?

Comment: 50nA is an extreme value at 85 degrees Celsius and a supply voltage of 15V. In practice, there may be a few pA currents there, so not for days, but for several hours the charge remains. The first pulse recharges the capacitor. So it works in standard applications where monostable starts more often, not once a day.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: I know that doesn't mean much, but the [model](https://imgur.com/a/xhpq3Hu) shows it. The input current is 8.7pA, the THR input rises very slowly.

Comment: @csabahu Makes sense. In my application I don't know how long the low level pulse is going to be. Would a 1M resistor between THR and ground be a straight up bad idea, do you think?

Comment: That resistance completely eliminates this little flaw, so it’s worth putting in there. Although redundant in 90% of cases, it will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question. My first thoughts were that something internal was acting as a pull-up. Examination of the block diagrams doesn't reveal any pull-up.

[image]

*No sign of a pull-up on the THR input here.*

My guess is that the diode's leakage current may be enough.
From Table 1.1 we learn that

```
Threshold Current (max) = 50 nA at VS = 15V
```

My theory doesn't hold up when we look at the 1N4148 datasheet.

[image]

*At 10 V reverse voltage the reverse current is only about 10 nA. [Vishay 1N4148 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf).*

The only way this theory could work is if the THR input is a guaranteed current source (rather than sink) in which case the output (and diode) will tend to charge up the input capacitor. The datasheet is not clear on the current direction.

Let's see if anyone else has some wisdom.

Comment: I was thinking that I needed a pull-down rather than a pull-up between THR and GND. The THR input should be low I think until the rising edge pulls it up and triggers the output. No?

Comment: Maybe, but notice that their timing diagram shows a falling edge just prior to the rising edge. I haven't the energy to read through the data sheet to figure it out.

Comment: `if the THR input is a guaranteed current source (rather than sink)` [ZSCT1555 from ZETEX](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZSCT1555.pdf) shows the internal schematic and the THRESHOLD input is a curent sink input -- as in conventional 555s. Maybe Microchip's (and MICREL's) THR pin configuration is different. Even if Microchip's THR pin is a current sink, the leakage current should be enough because THR input is the base of a Darlington pair.

Answer (score 0):

When the input transitions high, the left side of the cap is clamped to (Vout + 0.6 V).  When the input goes low, so does the THR input.  With the diode reverse-biased and a CMOS input, there is basically zero current going anywhere to change the voltage across the input cap.  The THR input can sit low for quite a while.  Eventually the input goes high, the left side of the cap crosses the THR trip point, and the output goes low.